# Open Source Objective-C Syntax Highlighter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting, uitextview

Can anyone point me in the direction of a project / framework / tutorial, preferably in Objective-C (or C/C++ I guess), that will demonstrate / handle syntax highlighting? I'd like it to work off of, and onto, the contents of a UITextView (iPhone / iPad), and I'd like it to support minimum, PHP, but preferably also Javascript / CSS / HTML, etc. I've had absolutely no luck googling, everything seems to be blog plugins, etc, for displaying colored content on your site in < pre > tags. I don't need it to do any syntax checking, just the coloring.

Thanks!

Comment: Well UITextView can't be done as it only supports plain text

Comment: I dont think, that there is a project, that meets all your requirements. But [Session 110 - Advanced Text Handling for iPhone OS](https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345597?i=1611967207) shows, what would be needed to realize such a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

review the source code of TexShop (http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) or Smultron (http://smultron.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I actually the notion the other day, that I should check out Smultron, but I had forgotten until just now! I'll investigate, and see what I find.

Answer (score 2):

What you are really searching for is usually called a "pretty printer".

For Objective-C, the Mac already has built in a nice formatter called Enscript - it can output eps but also HTML (and a few other formats).  An example command line that generates one HTML file with multiple highlighted and formatted files with a directory link is:

```
enscript -E --color --language=html --toc -pfile.html *.h *.m
```

It being open source, you should be able to adapt the source for use by Objective-C, probably unto a UIWebView... or if you had a lot of time, you could probably adapt the engine to spit out formatted UIAttributedStrings.  But it's a place to start at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VIM plugin for Cocoa/Objective-C - it may help!

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2674

**NOTE:**

People don't have to keep downvoting - It's not in a compilable code, nor in the format you want - I KNOW that - I'm just stating that here is a concise rule-file that describes the color highlighting ypu want for the language you want!

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be embeddable in an executable I write and distribute. Imagine I was writing Komodo, or an IDE like that. I know Komodo is Java, but still, I need the stuff in the binary to highlight.